# Wrong layout of CSS scroll table with three columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm building a table with three columns `IDServizio, NomeServizio, Descrizione`.

I'm trying to use a css that allows me to have the table with the scroll but I don't know how the layout is changed.

I would like to modify the CSS or html code to show the contents of each line of the description column without wrap.

Example (what I want) first row:

```
1        SearchCostruttore             Servizio che serve per ottenere la descrizione...
```

Now:

```
1        SearchCostruttore             Servizio che serve per ottenre  
                                       la descrizione relativa al costr
```

```css
    <style type="text/css">
      table.scroll {
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
        /*text-align: center;*/
      }

      table.scroll th,
      table.scroll td,
      table.scroll tr,
      table.scroll thead,
      table.scroll tbody {
        display: block;
      }

      table.scroll thead tr {
        /* fallback */
        width: 97%;
        /* minus scroll bar width */
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
        width: calc(100% - 16px);
      }

      table.scroll tr:after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
      }

      table.scroll tbody {
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      table.scroll tbody td,
      table.scroll thead th {
        width: 19%;
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }

      thead tr th {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        /*text-align: left;*/
      }

      tbody {
        border-top: 2px solid black;
      }

      tbody td:last-child,
      thead th:last-child {
        border-right: none !important;
      }
```

```html
  
  <body>
    <form>
      <table class="scroll">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID Servizio</th>
            <th>Nome Servizio</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>searchCostruttore</td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il costruttore tramite sigcos e dessig</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>searchStructureAgent</td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite codice e descrizione</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>getStructureAgent</td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite il codice</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I try to modify the code but I didn't succeed.

I am a beginner with the html language.

Comment: why are you lots of css add in to your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple way to create table

```css
table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="background:gray;">ID Servizio</th>
<th style="background:yellow;">Nome Servizio</th>
<th style="background:green;">Descrizione</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
 <td>searchCostruttore</td>
 <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il costruttore tramite sigcos e dessig</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
                <td>searchStructureAgent</td>
                <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite codice e descrizione</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
                <td>getStructureAgent</td>
                <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite il codice</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!! 
I wanted to try to implement the css but in this case it wasn't needed

Comment: excuse another question .. how do I color the columns of the table header?

Comment: you can set color as you choice check my last edited answer

Comment: happy to help my bro

Comment: can you remove the inside edge at each row?

Comment: sorry I explained myself badly, I want to delete the edge between '1' and 'searchCostruttore' and description

Comment: you want to remove td expan it i didn't understand

Comment: i prefer you plz you still read this articles you understand very well about table in html https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp